# Adobe AIR for Cross Platform - Desktop & Mobile Cross Platform Animation?

Tags: flash, animation, air, adobe, qml

I have to develop a huge set of interactive animation for deployment as application which should run on both desktop & mobile platform.

I have created demo subset in Qt/QML. Though i was able to achieve desired results, the time for development was significant. The same could be achieved easily in Adobe Flash in lesser time frame.

But as Adobe Flash has been discontinued officially from all major mobile platform, so, i am looking for alternative.

So, i have a set of queries:

- Could i use Adobe AIR as an alternative?
- If yes, Pros & Cons?
- What other options should i consider?

The animation would be interactive in nature and would also use 3D animation for 35% of the
total development.

Comment: I recommend reading this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4184675/1856411)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, Adobe Flash has been discontinued officially from all major mobile platform but recently I came across the tool which allows you to convert and play swf to some cross-platform frameworks like Cocos2d-x, Starling and Unity3d. It is called GAF converter. It supports masks, shape tweens, blur and glow. I don't have a huge ammount of animations as you but I think it doesn't metter how many animations you have. I am working on my iPad game now and use GAF converter as well. So far its performance is on the decent level.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that the link provided by CyanAngel is incredibly out of date. I'll try to write a more up-to-date version (the AIR Runtime has changed drastically since 2010):

- AIR is the Adobe Integrated Runtime. It basically allows you to write ActionScript 3 using the Flash and Flex SDKs that can run on various platforms as an application rather than as a file opened by the Flash Player in a browser.
- It needs to be stressed that AIR **is not** Flash. It uses the same base SDK (the Flash SDK), but the AIR runtime is completely separate from the Flash runtime. What you write for AIR can be modified to run in the Flash Player and Flash content can be modified to run in the AIR runtime. But it is not a 1-to-1 translation as the answer provided by CyanAngel indicates. It used to be, but over the years they have grown further and further apart (mainly the AIR Runtime has been gaining more and more native functionality that is needed for apps but not needed and not available for SWFs)
- Your app would be compiled as either an IPA (iOS), APK (Android), DMG (Mac), EXE (Windows), or .air (Mac + Windows). For iOS, the compiler cross-compiles the AS3 to native Objective-C code. The process is quite slow, though there have apparently been massive strides made to improve that in AIR 4.0 (in beta). For the rest, the AS3 is actually run through the AIR Runtime, which can be viewed as a Flash Player equivalent). For Android, the runtime is generally bundled ("Captive Runtime"), and it is *always* bundled with DMGs and EXEs. For the .air type and non-captive Android projects, a separate Adobe AIR app is required to run the application.
- If you are running the Flex SDK, there is even less of a 1-to-1 translation. For mobile projects in the Flex SDK, you are expected to provide multiple assets to cover various ranges of screen resolutions. This does not work on desktop and does not work in-browser. The main structural classes used in the Flex SDK for mobile projects (`ViewNavigator`, `View`) are *only* available on mobile. So any project built using these components will not be possible to run on desktop or in-browser.
- There are many pros and cons. This really isn't the place to list them all, but in general the pros are that it is one code-base that will run on 4 different platforms, 5 if you include the 3rd-party BlackBerry 10 AIR SDK. Cons range from how difficult it is to get more complicated things to work properly cross-platform to the nearly complete lack of native controls (no access to things like alerts and notifications and toasts and volume). You can gain access to these controls through AIR Native Extensions (ANEs), however
- For anything relying on heavy animation, it is recommended you use GPU rendering and use `Stage3D` (and its various related components) to handle the rendering. For basic apps using the Flex SDK, using Direct Render mode is generally fine. For games or vector-based animations, you'll want to use Stage3D, however, and look into using a GPU-based GUI framework such as Starling (you will find that Starling is heavily recommended)

Hopefully that helps. I also recommend my answer to a previous question, [How can I develop mobile apps using Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569368/how-can-i-develop-mobile-apps-using-flash/19570973#19570973), which covers a few other items related to developing in AIR.